# Will table-valued functions act like views, in being optimized by the database engine?

Tags: sql-server, view, user-defined-functions

I only saw one comment that looked like it might address this, and that is that both the inline function and the view are expanded by the engine.  Not sure if that is what I need.

I'm converting some stuff out of Qlikview back to SQL Server, and trying to optimize speed.

I put everything into table returning functions and use a view as the final object called by Qlikview, just to keep the interface from being overly cluttered.

I want to know if I'm shooting myself in the foot by going with the functions.  Almost all of them are inline, with a couple that are multi-statement.

So, I guess, what I need to know is, if a view is composed of several functions, will the engine do the filtering of the functions based on final where clauses, so that not everything is pulled from each function, but only the stuff that meets the where statement.  And I mean along the way, not at the final moment.

Answer (score 1):

The inline functions act like parameterized views. The query processor already has functionality for correlated joins (joins whose source table reference outer columns) because you can write those with `CROSS APPLY` already. Joining to an inline TVP's is like writing a `CROSS APPLY` to the query optimizer.

The multi-valued functions are not going to behave that way. Make sure that they are not being called too often and that you don't loose too much by not having them inlined. They will not benefit from optimizer transforms in a holistic way.